# Custom C++ Allocator cause error in : _Container_base12::_Orphan_all_unlocked_v3()

Tags: c++, vector, stl, allocator

So I intend to use this stack-based allocator for std::vector, and I use 2 arrays for the allocation(because vectors grow and copy the old buffer to the new).

Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>
#include <array>

using size_t = std::size_t;
using byte = std::byte;

template <class T, size_t capacity = 512>
class stack_allocator
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

    using pointer = value_type*;
    using const_pointer = typename std::pointer_traits<pointer>::template rebind<value_type const>;
    using void_pointer = typename std::pointer_traits<pointer>::template rebind<void>;
    using const_void_pointer = typename std::pointer_traits<pointer>::template rebind<const void>;

    using difference_type = typename std::pointer_traits<pointer>::difference_type;
    using size_type = std::make_unsigned_t<difference_type>;

    template <class U> struct rebind { typedef stack_allocator<U, capacity> other; };

    stack_allocator() noexcept {};  // not required, unless used
    ~stack_allocator() noexcept = default;

    //stack_allocator(stack_allocator&&) = delete;
    //stack_allocator& operator=(stack_allocator&&) = delete;
    //stack_allocator(const stack_allocator&) = delete;
    //stack_allocator& operator=(const stack_allocator&) = delete;

    template <class U>
    stack_allocator(stack_allocator<U> const&) noexcept {}
    // ? is n already aligned ?
    inline pointer allocate(size_t n)
    {
        constexpr auto max_size_allowed = (capacity>>1);
        auto size = n * sizeof(value_type); 
        if (size > max_size_allowed)
        {
            return static_cast<pointer>(::operator new (size));
        }
        else
        {
            m_Index = !m_Index;
            return static_cast<pointer>(static_cast<void*>(&m_Array[static_cast<size_t>(m_Index)][0]));
        }
    }

    inline void deallocate(pointer p, size_t n) noexcept
    {
        constexpr auto max_size_allowed = (capacity>>1);
        auto size = n * sizeof(value_type);
        if (size > max_size_allowed)
            ::operator delete(p);
        else
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    inline pointer allocate(size_t n, const_void_pointer)
    {
        return allocate(n);
    }

    template <class U, class ...Args>
    void construct(U* p, Args&& ...args)
    {
        ::new(p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <class U>
    void destroy(U* p) noexcept
    {
        p->~U();
    }

    inline constexpr size_t max_size() const noexcept
    {
        return std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(T);
    }

    stack_allocator select_on_container_copy_construction() const
    {
        return *this;
    }

    using propagate_on_container_copy_assignment = std::true_type;
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::false_type;
    using propagate_on_container_swap = std::true_type;
    using is_always_equal = std::true_type;

protected:
    //const bool is_pointer_in_range(byte* p) const noexcept { return (p >= &m_Array[0]) && (p <= &m_Array[capacity - 1]); }

    bool m_Index{ false };
    byte m_Array[2][(capacity >> 1)]{ {static_cast<byte>(0)} };
};

template <class T, size_t capacity, class U>
bool operator==(stack_allocator<T, capacity> const&, stack_allocator<U, capacity> const&) noexcept
{
    return true;
}

template <class T, size_t capacity, class U>
bool operator!=(stack_allocator<T, capacity> const& x, stack_allocator<U, capacity> const& y) noexcept
{
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<int, stack_allocator<int, 512>> stackVec;
    stackVec.push_back(1);
    stackVec.push_back(2);
    stackVec.push_back(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Somehow the code cause crash:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqZSt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3NR5.png)

I've notice that the "_Container_base12" inherits from the allocator, so I guess there must be something wrong with my "stack_allocator" implementation. But I can't figure it out.

Hope to know what is the correct way of writing an allocator.

Comment: Allocators are required to be copyable and movable. They are routinely passed around by  value. `allocate` may well be called on a temporary, or a short-lived local variable; the memory behind the returned pointer is expected to outlive the instance of the allocator. In practice, `std::vector` implementation likely does something like `Internal* p = Alloc::rebind<Internal>::other(alloc).allocate()` for its own internal needs. You then hand out a pointer that will become dangling shortly. This whole idea of keeping memory inside the allocator instance is not gonna fly.

Comment: The shown images carry no useful information, referencing classes and backtraces that don't appear to have any relevance to the shown code. I see nothing obvious in the shown code that would explain a crash. I can compile and run the shown code without issues, without crashing, and running it through valgrind shows no memory errors. Unable to reproduce any problem from the shown code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Try MSVC with iterator debugging on. The implementation then allocates additional internal data structures to track invalidated iterators, and uses the provided allocator for that. This often weeds out non-conforming custom allocators.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. Even though in this example, it’s better to write a small_vector other than a stack_allocator. But I thought I could also use the idea for std::string, for small object optimization. Guess I have to find an another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik), I was able to find out the issue. After some research, I also found out that, it is actually easy to do this in C++17, we could either do:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 64> memory;
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource pool{ memory.data(), memory.size() };

// then we can define our vector using stack memory
std::vector<int, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int>> vec{&pool};
```

or, we can put the "std::array<unsigned char, 64> memory" inside a custom memory_resource.

In my case, I want to use in-place array for small objects to avoid 'allocations'. And for large objects, I want to use pooled memory.

So I inherited from _Identity_equal_resource and use a global unsynchronized_pool_resource behind the scene.

Now everything is just looking perfect to me.

```
// Note: still testing this.
template<size_t local_arena_size>
struct LocalArenaMemoryResource : public std::pmr::_Identity_equal_resource
{
private:
    static inline constexpr size_t max_blocks_per_chunk = 16;
    static inline constexpr size_t largest_required_pool_block = 16 * 1024;
    static inline std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource _pool{ std::pmr::pool_options { max_blocks_per_chunk, largest_required_pool_block } };
private:
    using base = std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource;
    void* do_allocate(size_t _Bytes, size_t _Align) override
    {
        if (_Bytes <= local_arena_size)
        {
            return static_cast<void*>(&m_local_buffer[0]);
        }

        return _pool.allocate(_Bytes, _Align);
    }

    void do_deallocate(void* _Ptr, size_t _Bytes, size_t _Align) override
    {
        if (_Ptr >= &m_local_buffer[0] && _Ptr < &m_local_buffer[local_arena_size - 1])
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            _pool.deallocate(_Ptr, _Bytes, _Align);
        }
    }

private:
    std::array<byte, local_arena_size> m_local_buffer;
};
```

There are things I'm still learning, such as: how unsynchronized_pool_resource handles the allocation when oversize alloc is required. Also I'm wondering if a fixed_block_pool will be more efficient. Still learning, testing, but it's really fun.